# (Flutter) CognitoUserSession is not valid because idToken is null

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-cognito, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using AWS Cognito and Flutter framework to build an app.
The cognito suddenly is not working when I changed the layout(?) of the app, please help me out!

When I first built the app I made it so the login page would come up first but now I changed the page layout so the users can login after looking around the app.

Thisis what I get in the console when I hit the login button:

```
W/CognitoUserSession(22147): CognitoUserSession is not valid because idToken is null.
D/AWSMobileClient(22147): Sending password.
D/AWSMobileClient(22147): Using USER_SRP_AUTH for flow type.
E/UserContextDataProvider(22147): Exception in creating JSON from context data
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(22147): AuthException
I/flutter (22147): Could not login - Sign in failed
```

this is how my Widget build in main looked like before:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Photo Gallery App',
  theme: ThemeData(visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
  home: StreamBuilder<AuthState>(
    stream: _authService.authStateController.stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Navigator(
          pages: [
            if (snapshot.data!.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.login)
              MaterialPage(
                  child: LoginPage(
                      didProvideCredentials: _authService.loginWithCredentials,
                      shouldShowSignUp: _authService.showSignUp
                  )
              ),
            if (snapshot.data!.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.signUp)
              MaterialPage(
                  child: SignUpPage(
                    didProvideCredentials: _authService.signUpWithCredentials,
                    shouldShowLogin: _authService.showLogin
                  )
              ),
            if (snapshot.data!.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.verification)
              MaterialPage(
                child: VerificationPage(
                  didProvideVerificationCode: _authService.verifyCode
                )
              ),
            if (snapshot.data!.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.session)
              MaterialPage(
                child: CameraFlow(shouldLogOut: _authService.logOut)
              )
          ],
          onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
        );
      } else {
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    }
  )
);}
```

Now, it looks like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'App',
  theme: ThemeData(visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
  home: StreamBuilder<AuthState>(
    stream: AuthService.authStateController.stream, // PREVIOUS: _authService.authStateController.stream
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Navigator(
          pages: [
            if (snapshot.data!.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.none || snapshot.data!.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.session)
              MaterialPage(
                child: TabBarFlow(
                    authFlowStatus: snapshot.data!.authFlowStatus,
                    shouldShowSignUp: _authService.showSignUp,
                    shouldShowLogin: _authService.showLogin,
                )
              ),
            if (snapshot.data!.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.login)
              MaterialPage(
                  child: LoginPage(
                      didProvideCredentials: _authService.loginWithCredentials,
                      shouldShowSignUp: _authService.showSignUp,
                      shouldShowNone: _authService.showNone,
                  )
              ),

            if (snapshot.data!.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.signUp)
              MaterialPage(
                  child: SignUpPage(
                      didProvideCredentials: _authService.signUpWithCredentials,
                      shouldShowLogin: _authService.showLogin,
                      shouldShowNone: _authService.showNone,
                  )
              ),

            if (snapshot.data!.authFlowStatus == AuthFlowStatus.verification)
              MaterialPage(
                child: VerificationPage(
                  didProvideVerificationCode: _authService.verifyCode
                )
              )
          ],
          onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
        );
      } else {
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    }
  ),
);}
```

I think the problem might be coming from TabbarFlow which looks like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  HomePage(),
  SearchAvatarPage(),
  SelectAvatarPage(),
  MyPage(),
  SettingsPage(
      authFlowStatus: widget.authFlowStatus,
      shouldShowSignUp: widget.shouldShowSignUp,
      shouldShowLogin: widget.shouldShowLogin
  )
];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: ''
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          label: ''
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              width: 35,
              height: 35,
              color:Color.fromRGBO(37, 67, 117, 1),
              child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white)
            )
          ),
        label: ''
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
          label: ''
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu_outlined),
          label: ''
      )
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
  ),
);}
```

Amplify logic

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:amplify_auth_cognito/amplify_auth_cognito.dart';
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify.dart';

import 'auth_credentials.dart';

enum AuthFlowStatus  { none, login, signUp, verification, session }

class AuthState {
  final AuthFlowStatus authFlowStatus;

  AuthState({required this.authFlowStatus});
}

class AuthService {
  static final authStateController = StreamController<AuthState>();

  late AuthCredentials _credentials;

  void showNone() {
    final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.none);
    authStateController.add(state);
  }

  void showSignUp() {
    final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.signUp);
    authStateController.add(state);
  }

  void showLogin() {
    final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.login);
    authStateController.add(state);
  }

  void loginWithCredentials(AuthCredentials credentials) async {
    try {

      final result = await Amplify.Auth.signIn(
        username: credentials.username, password: credentials.password
      );

      if (result.isSignedIn) {
        final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.session);
        authStateController.add(state);
      } else {
        print('User could not be signed in');
      }
    } on AuthException catch (authError) {
      print('Could not login - ${authError.message}');
    }
  }

  void signUpWithCredentials(SignUpCredentials credentials) async {
    try {
      final userAttributes = {'email': credentials.email};

      final result = await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
        username: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password,
        options: CognitoSignUpOptions(userAttributes: userAttributes)
      );

      if (result.isSignUpComplete) {
        loginWithCredentials(credentials);
      } else {
        this._credentials = credentials;

        final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.verification);
        authStateController.add(state);
      }
    } on AuthException catch (authError) {
      print('Failed to sign up - ${authError.message}');
    }
  }

  void verifyCode(String verificationCode) async {
    try {
      final result = await Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp(
        username: _credentials.username, confirmationCode: verificationCode
      );

      if (result.isSignUpComplete) {
        loginWithCredentials(_credentials);
      } else {
        // Add later
      }
    } on AuthException catch (authError) {
      print('Could not verify code - ${authError.message}');
    }
  }

  void checkAuthStatus() async {
    try {
      await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession();

      final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.session);
      authStateController.add(state);
    } catch (_) {
      final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.none);
      authStateController.add(state);
    }
  }

  static void logOut() async {
    try {
      await Amplify.Auth.signOut();

      final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.none);
      authStateController.add(state);
    } on AuthException catch (authError) {
      print('Could not log out - ${authError.message}');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Amplify logic?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Hi there, not sure what you mean exactly by amplify logic.... sorry I'm just a beginner but I think you mean this(please check out the last code section in my post)

Comment: @gs97ahn -- Have you ever found solution to this? I am also getting similar error after I upgraded my flutter and mac.